# How to find the storage size of objects in Cassandra using CLI?

Tags: cassandra, storage, command-line-interface

How do I find out the storage size of something I inserted into a column family using the CLI?

I want to compare the object's size in [Cassandra](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apache_Cassandra) to its actual size.